# How to obtain Spring transaction manager instance?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-3, spring-transactions

I use annotations to mark methods which should be executed in a transaction.

But, in one place I need to do `transactionManager.rollback()` manually, without annotation. How can I obtain `transactionManager` object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to rollback the current transaction, you may use

```
    TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Note that it doesn't rollback the transaction immediately - it sets the "rollback only" status, so transaction will be rolled back during attempt to commit.

---

Otherwise, if you need a programmatic transaction demaracation, you may use `TransactionTemplate`, as described in [10.6 Programmatic transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic).

Also you can obtain an instance of `PlatformTransactionManager`, but it's not widely used since `TransactionTemplate` is a recommended approach for programmatic transaction demaracation.

**See also:**

- [10. Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your object is configured by Spring you could off course inject a transactionmanager into it...