# How to access Object in @AfterThrowing Method in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

```
public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction){

}

@AfterThrowing(execution="(..)")
```

I am doing a Transaction and I want to throw an exception and get it caught in AOP `@AfterThrowing` Method. I want to access the object that was passed in my method and use it in the `@AfterThrowing` Method

I want to use that transaction object in my afterthrowing method. How to do it?

Comment: This unclear question already received 4 close votes. Please update the question to be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of keeping Essex Boy guessing what the heck you might want to know. Does nobody learn how to ask questions anymore? It is such a basic ability. Just imagine you read this question, having no other context and code. Could you possibly answer it by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an around advice, something like:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(hello.LogException")
    public Object handelLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

      try {    
        return joinPoint.proceed();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // based on the exception that will cause a transaction rollback call your method here
        throw e;
      }
    }
}
```

Not sure why you need the transaction, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123355/how-to-obtain-spring-transaction-manager-instance) for help getting the current transaction.

Also see [hibernate interceptors](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-interceptor) which has an [afterTransactionCompletion method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#afterTransactionCompletion(org.hibernate.Transaction))

Comment: I am doing a transaction therefore at some point the transaction can fail. So I want to update that the transaction has failed in the database. Therefore if the transaction fails, it will give an exception and if there is an exception I want that @AfterThrowing method is called so that I can save that the transaction failed in database.

Comment: it's the other way round, your code will throw and exception and that will call the transaction to be rolled back

Comment: After Rollback I want a certain method to be executed?

Comment: you can add that in the catch block, see the updated answer

Comment: I tried the same but the code in the catch block is getting executed but is not being saved in the database using jpa save method.